# how to convert strings into arrays using php

Tags: php, mysql, string, random

I have a stored string that echoes like this

```
$string = 24,56,43,23,45;
```

I want to retrieve data from mysql, so I do this;

```
$getcompany = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = $string");
```

If the id matches any of the strings, it should show that info but nothing happens. I tried using explode to breakdown the strings but I don't know how to make the query loop through the string to display the info that matches the string.

I hope am making sense to someone :( pls help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `IN`:

```
$string = "24,56,43,23,45";
$getcompany = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id IN (" . $string . ")");
```

Which would translate in to the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pages
WHERE  id IN (24,56,43,23,45);
```

As long as `id` is a numeric field that will work. If `id` is a string, you can rework it a bit:

```
$string = "24,56,43,23,45";
$args = "'" . implode("','", explode(",", $string)) . "'";
$getcompany = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id IN (" . $args . ")");
```

Which would translate to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pages
WHERE  id IN ('24','56','43','23','45');
```

Comment: wow...this is awesome! Need to find a good mysql book to read. Any recommendations??? @Brad

Comment: @JaySmoke: just the [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you'd use `IN`:

```
$nums = "'24','56','43','23','45'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id IN (". $nums .");"
```

Comment: thanx mate :) you are far too kind

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is to first split the string on the commas and then use an `IN` clause in the query:

```
$string = '24,56,43,23,45';
$string = explode(',', $string);

$getcompany = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id IN($string)");
```

I assume that your `id` column is numeric so this shouldn't require putting quotes around the numbers.